# Setup Mailx command in linux

Tags: command-line, mailx

Set up for mailx command in Linux to send mail is done by using following code snippet in /etc/mail.rc

```
`
    set smtp=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    set from=XXX@xxx.com
    set password=XXXXXXXX
`
```

So I can send mail successfully but the problem is I can not receive any mails from outside of the linux environment.

Help me to setup mailx for receiving mails also.
I am new to mailx so if I am wrong at any point then please correct me !

Answer (score 0):

check that firewall settings that may block incoming emails

$ sudo service iptables status 
or
$ sudo systemctl status iptables